# Insert query foreach loop trouble

Tags: php, mysql, loops, foreach, insert

*I don't have to worry about mysql depreciation, nor SQL injections, just a personal project*

My Code:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { // check if the user submits data (POST) or just loads the page (GET)
$error = false;
$required = array('uexam_id', 'usubject', 'uexam_date'); //VALIDATION: first check all required fields are not empty.


foreach($required as $field) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $error = true;
        break;
    }
}
//if a field was empty, show error
if ($error) {
    die("All fields required!!! <a href='examisud.php'> Back to PHP Form </a>");
} else {
    $InsertQuery = "INSERT INTO Exam (exam_id, subject, exam_date) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["uexam_id"], $con)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["usubject"], $con)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["uexam_date"], $con)."')";
    $result = mysql_query($InsertQuery, $con) or die('query Failure:'. mysql_error());
}
}
```

I have a superficial/aesthetic problem here.
The insert/update/delete queries work fine however this foreach loop seems to be giving me trouble.
Everytime I navigate to this page (examisud), I get the error "All fields required". Except, there's not actually any error happening, it's just displaying the message. That's on page load for some reason.
Also, whenever I update or delete, the error message displays again, but the values in the fields are updated/deleted like they are supposed to.
It's weird, i'm hoping someone can point me the way to stopping this loop from appearing only when I need it to, which is when a field is left blank???
Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Try changing `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {` to `if(!empty($_POST)) {`

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger no, that didn't work, exact same thing unfortunately :/

Comment: Do you mean you are seeing the error on page _load_ or _reload_? If on _load_, could you paste the full page code?

Comment: Are you sure if the values are getting inserted into the database because I you feel there is a problem in your query which has $con in every bracket after VALUES, which is uncalled for.

Comment: My values are defo getting put into the database. I have the phpmyadmin open in another window and refresh to check it after every query and it's working just fine.

Comment: You need show the form which passes the values to this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Your condition makes true every time on Page load.

Remove this: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')`

Use this: `if (!empty($_POST))`

Answer (score 0):

just debug it to see which field makes your $error equals true:

```
foreach($required as $field) {
    if (!isset($_POST[$field]) || empty($_POST[$field])) {
        $error = true;
        echo 'Im an empty field that causes you trouble: ' . $field;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what echoed out on screen:

**Im an empty field that causes you trouble: uexam_idAll fields required!!! Back to PHP Form**

so uexam_id is giving me trouble somehow???

Comment: That came up on page load too btw.

Comment: then this field: uexam_id is arriving empty.

Comment: @user3473793 Are you opening this page in your browser? Or are you being sent to this page from a form of another page?

Comment: and please change your first if from this: `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` to this: `if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {`

Comment: @Fadey @I Can Haz Cheezburger but That shows before I even insert anything? I come to the page via a select statement from a html page which brings me to the php form and that error "All fields required" pops up before I even enter any data.
And after using your suggestion fadey "Im an empty field that causes you trouble: uexam_idAll fields required!!! Back to PHP Form" shows up at the top of the page before I even go near the form.

Comment: please change your if statement to the one I posted in the past comment, from `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` to this: `if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))`

Comment: Now the insert statement doesn't work at all. And on page load it says at the top "Im an empty field that causes you trouble: uexam_id" :/

Comment: you have an empty uexam_id that is arriving empty from your POST, please check that on your form. and make sure you are not submitting the form when refreshing.

Comment: But nothing is being entered? I start off on a HTML page. On this HTML page there is NO form. Just a select statement which takes you to the form which is on the PHP page. On the php page load up in my original code I had **All fields required! Go back to form** and in my code gotten from you now, I have my php form but at the top I have **"Im an empty field that causes you trouble: uexam_id"**
Nothing is arriving anywhere, on page load, it automatically assumes that i've not entered in the first field and tells me to fill it in before I even have a chance to put anything in the form.

Comment: something makes this uexam_id showing up in the $_POST global, either a form is being submitted or a value is being pushed into $_POST global. try to copy this code to a separate file on your server and run it, see if you get that error. I just run your code with the my changes, and nothing gets printed out. so your code seems to be working fine.

Comment: The code works, it's only an aesthetic problem, I want to get the error message only to display when it's supposed to, but it does it on page load, update and when I delete :/

Ok, I'll try that next! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user3473793 If you are coming to this page through another page through `POST` then these methods won't work for you and you need to check for that separately. You said the you come via a select statement. Is that on form submission or a simple redirect?

Comment: I was just running the code as is, not from submitting a form. I got nothing echoed out by php using this code, so it seems to be fine. Check the rest of your app, maybe your missing something out